# PHP Loops not working while using ajax for dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've recently tried to turn a website of mine a bit more dynamic. It's heavily based on php and I tried looking into having pages changed dynamically with ajax.
However, I've stumbled upon a problem with having php loops loaded through ajax.
I've looked up a script for making dynamic pages possible: http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

```
switch($_GET['page'])  {
case 'page1' : $page = 'Page 1';
                break;
case 'page2' : $page = 'Page 2';
                break;
case 'page3' : $page = 'Page 3';
                break;
case 'page4' : $page = 'Page 4';
                break;
}
echo $page;
```

For example, if you change

```
 case 'page1' : $page = 'Page 1';
```

into a loop

```
 case 'page1' : for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){$page .= $i;};
```

it just doesn't do anything. Any ideas? :)

EDIT: I'm expecting it to output what the given loop normally outputs. There seems to be conflict of some sort when it's being dealt with. The posted code without loop works as intended, but when you bring php loops into play it won't work.

EDIT2: I've pinpointed the problem to be the loops, so I don't think it is necessary to bring out the code I'm using. I just put a simple loop there as an example. The code is just basically looping through data entries in database and outputting them. I'd love if someone could point out why this does not work and if there is a work-around. :P

Comment: What are you expecting as a result of the loop?

Comment: What is the actual code you are trying to use with this loop?  (note `$page` is initially undefined)

Comment: Try dropping the semicolon after your for loop, curly-braced code blocks and incorrect placement of semicolons can cause strange results

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you if you don't post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Link at the top has all the necessary code (js & php part). Essentially, if I am able to reproduce the problem at a much more simpler scale, why would you need a much more complicated version of it? :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use a for loop as a value for a case statement.  See the result below:

http://ideone.com/GXXMs

Without seeing your real code and knowing your real objectives, my best advice is to preprocess your loops **before** entering that switch statement.

Comment: That isn't what the OP is doing. The loop is in the body of the case, which is fine.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding... But essentially I took his actual code and replaced what he said to replace.  Syntax error.

Comment: Syntax error is in the loop; $i=0;$i<2;i++ --> $i=0;$i<2;$i++

Comment: @user1524849... Good catch... Still the same parse error, though.  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOR in...`

Comment: @JaredCobb you are attempting to assign to `$page` from the loop on the left. The OP is assigning in the loop body.

Comment: Try removing '$page = ' part before the for loop, works for me at least.

Comment: @Michael - Of course!  I did misunderstand. You're correct of course.  Looks like the OP edited his code to reflect your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue ins't trying to execute a loop within a PHP case.

It appears that you are using the $_GET['page'] call to grab the value from the QueryString.  This would work if you defined "page" in the URL syntax (ex: foo.php?page=page1).  In this example, you never define the variable called "page" in the query string, instead just throwing the #page1 at the end of the URL.  This means none of the cases in your switch statement are executing because they don't match the null value returned by the $_GET.

Try parsing the query string to get whatever is after the "#" into the parameter you use in your case statement.

Comment: I don't understand. If that is the case, then the code shouldn't have worked in the first place before introducing loops into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expression replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
echo preg_replace('/page([0-9]+)/i', 'Page $1', $_GET['page']);
```

The reason `case 'page1' : for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){$page .= $i;};` does nothing is `$page` is null. Try

```
case 'page1' : $page = 'page'; for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){$page .= $i;};
```

Answer (score 0):

When I put your loop into a function:

function testthis()
{
for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++){$page .= $i;};
}

It throws an error: "Notice: Undefined variable: page in demo.php"

When I declare $page outside of the loop - just put in the line: $page = ""; it works - no error.

So - my recommendation - declare $page outside the loop and set it to an empty string "". See if that fixes the issue.

The root cause seems to be that you're concatenating a string to a variable that has not yet been declared.